# Web beautifulsoup request scraping too slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

im trying to boost the speed of my code, i dont know why this take
2:30 minutes to get only 210 products for one WebPage (I only want
that products that have 50% or more). I hope you can help me because i
want to try to get all products in that place. thanks.

```
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import locale 
        import pandas as pd

        baseurl = 'https://www.elpalaciodehierro.com'
        headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
        }
        productlinks = []
        my_links = ['https://www.elpalaciodehierro.com/electronica/computadoras/laptops/?sz=153']

        for my_link in my_links:
            for number in range(1):
                #page = requests.get(my_link+str(number))

                    r = requests.get(my_link+str(number))
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
                    productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='l-plp-grid_item m-product')

                    for item in productlist:
                        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
                            productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])
                  
            
            laptopslist = []
            for link in productlinks:
                    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
                    name = soup.find('h1', class_='b-product_main_info-name').text.strip()
                    price = (soup.find('span', class_='b-product_price-value').text.strip())
                    try:
                        price_old = (soup.find('div', class_='b-product_price-sales m-reduced').text.strip())
                    except:
                        price_old = ('0')
                        
                    highss = str(price.replace('$',''))
                    lowss = str(price_old.replace('$',''))

                    highs = str(highss.replace(',',''))
                    lows = str(lowss.replace(',',''))

                    high = float(highs)
                    low = float(lows)
                    
                    if low > 0:
                        percent2 =  ((high-low))
                        percent1 = (((percent2/high)*100))
                        percent = (percent1)
                    elif low == 0 or low == ('0'):
                        percent = 0
                 
                    laptops = { 
                    'producto': name,
                    'precio ': price, 
                    'oferta': price_old,
                    'porcent': percent,
                    'link': link,
                        }
                    
                    laptopslist.append(laptops)
                    print('saving', laptops['producto']) 
                    
        df = pd.DataFrame(laptopslist)

        data_filter = df.porcent >= 50
        df[data_filter]

        df[data_filter].to_csv('data.csv')
```

I really know that im using a lot of processing but i hope it could be faster, is only page, please i want to get more products

Hardware is Ryzen 5 (3500u) 8 gb Ram, the website is faster.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons it could be running slow besides your code. What type of hardware are you running? Does the website you are scraping have good performance? How large of a file is the website your are scraping? Add more details.

Comment: Measure the time of your code and figure out what is the slowest part. Then focus on fixing it.